# Cuda video encode, convert from unsigned char * cb to NALs Unit, to send over the network

Tags: video, cuda, h.264, encode, nvidia

I have been playing around with the cudaencode example included in the 5.0 SDK. It takes a YUV (uncompressed video) file as input and writes out a raw H.264 stream (or can be VC1 also). The work is performed by the "NVEncodeFrame" function that is part of the Encoder API. The program takes a FILE object (stdio.h) as the output to where the result of the encoding (the compressed H.264 video) is written. Now I want to stream the video, as it is being encoded, into the networks.

My specific questions is:

1. Is there a way to convert "unsigned char * cb" in HandleReleaseBitStream(int nBytesInBuffer, unsigned char *cb,void *pUserData) to NALs and numberOfNals?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use [libh264bitstream](http://sourceforge.net/projects/h264bitstream/)'s [find_nal_unit()](http://h264bitstream.sourceforge.net/doxygen/0.1.5/h264__stream_8c.html#a6).  Call this repeatedly on your data until you have found all the nals.  This does assume/require that the nals have the standard nal prefix.  Also, this won't find the *last* nal in a buffer: you could either just assume everything from the end of last nal found to end of buffer is one more nal, or otherwise, append the next buffer to the remaining data and continue parsing.

You could also try using libavformat's `av_read_frame()`, which should return nals (as `AVPacket`s) when reading from a raw H.264 stream ([sample code](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/demuxing_8c_source.html)).  This is probably way more complicated.